# Installing VTK for C++

Tags: c++, vtk, linux-mint

I am using the [JuPedSim framework](https://github.com/JuPedSim/JuPedSim) on the [Mint operating system](https://linuxmint.com/).
From its official website, its requirement is to install [VTK](https://www.vtk.org/) for the g ++ compiler.

How can you set up the requirement, possibly from the terminal?

Comment: See [here](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Building/Linux) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306682/how-to-install-vtk-with-python-wrapper-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-rhel)

Comment: They give instructions [here](http://www.jupedsim.org/2016-11-03-requirements.html)